# BeforeScenario and AfterScenario hooks not working in specflow

Tags: selenium, specflow

I have the following code in my SeleniumSteps.cs code
I am trying to get the AfterScenario to fire on debugging these tests

```
using PrivateDomain;
using Machine.Specifications;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Functional.Steps
{
    public class SeleniumSteps : PrivateDomain.Steps.SeleniumSteps
    {
        #region Hooks
        [BeforeScenario]
        public void Before()
        {
            // before 
        }

        [AfterTestRun, Scope(Tag = null)]
        public new static void AfterTestRun()
        {
            // after testrun
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenarioErrorScreenshot()
        {
            // after scenario
        }

        #endregion
    }
}





using OpenQA.Selenium;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace PrivateDomain.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    [Scope(Tag = "Selenium")]
    public class SeleniumSteps
    {
        protected static IWebDriver webDriver;

        public SeleniumSteps();

        public virtual IWebDriver WebDriver { get; }

        [AfterTestRun]
        [Scope(Tag = null)]
        public static void AfterTestRun();

        [AfterScenarioAttribute(new[] { })]
        public virtual void AfterScenario();

    }
}
```

My feature file looks like this:
(Details removed)

```
@Customer_Portal
Feature: Account Management - Registration
    In order to create an account
    As a customer
    I want to register my details with the application

Scenario: Register

    # Registration Form
    When I navigate to "/Customer/Account/Register"
    // more code...


Scenario: Required Fields

    // more code...

Scenario: Invalid Contact Details

    // more code...

Scenario: Insufficient Password Strength

    // more code...

Scenario: Password Mismatch

    // more code...

Scenario: Already Registered

    // more code...

Scenario: Invalid Activation

    // more code...

Scenario: Already Activated

   // more code...
```

When I debug a test, I can see the debugger hitting the AfterTestRun portion.
However, neither the `BeforeScenario` or the `AfterScenario` are being exercised.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as Sandesh noted in his answer, you are missing `[Binding]` attribute for your `SeleniumSteps` subclass. It's not enough to have `[Binding]` only in base class, you must apply it to every class where are your hook methods or step definitions (bindings), because that is the way how specflow is searching for hooks and bindings under the hood. It is like scope identifier. If you miss to place `[Binding]` attribute to class, specflow will not search for potential hook methods or bindings in that class. Link on documentation: https://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/

This link can be useful also. Check answer given by RunOfTheShipe: [Specflow test step inheritance causes "Ambiguous step definitions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433031/specflow-test-step-inheritance-causes-ambiguous-step-definitions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - [Binding] attribute is present. I tried the steps you mention but unfortunately the same result. Would you know why AfterTestRun is successfully called but the others aren't?

Comment: No, i wouldn't know why is like that. Can you edit your question, and provide a bit more information about class where your hooks are defined?
And is that class of yours used anywhere else - for inheritance?

Comment: can you show your .feature file? And tags associated with feature and scenarios. Please update your question with it.

Comment: Ok, there are few solutions.Try next:
1. can you remove `[Scope(Tag = "Selenium")]` from `public class SeleniumSteps`, or
2. just add another Scope attribute for same class, like : `[Scope(Tag = "Customer_Portal")]`, or
3. just add new `@Selenium` tag to your `Feature: Account Management - Registration`

Comment: thanks guys - suggestion number 3 is what worked for me. the base class is actually coming from a dll so I can't change that. adding the tag in my feature file worked for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205145/discussion-between-stefan-zivkovic-and-dstewart101).

Answer (score 2):

You have missed [Binding] attribute in your SeleniumSteps

```
    namespace Functional.Steps
    {
         [Binding]
        public class SeleniumSteps : PrivateDomain.Steps.SeleniumSteps
        {
            #region Hooks
            [BeforeScenario]
            public void Before()
            {
                // before 
            }
}
}
```