# How is best to introduce a Base class for Specflow? This one isn't working

Tags: c#, specflow, extentreports

anyone know how to create a baseclass so that step definitions can inherit? Need to intergrate extent reports in a [setup] for it. I have tried this one but does not output

```
public class BaseClass(){
[Before]
public class void BeforeTests(){

console.writeline("This runs before the tests");

//Extent reports setup code here
}
[After]
public class void AfterTests(){

//Extent reports flush code here
console.writeline("This runs after the tests");
}
}
```

```
[Bindings]
public class StepDefinitionFile: BaseClass
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no good way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433031/specflow-test-step-inheritance-causes-ambiguous-step-definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just using hooks, you do not need a base class. Instead, create a class that specializes in the Extend Report logic. No need to inherit from this class in your other step definitions:

```
[Binding]
public class ExtentReports
{
    [Before]
    public void BeforeScenario(ScenarioInfo scenario)
    {
        // Extent report logic
    }

    [After]
    public void AfterScenario(ScenarioInfo scenario)
    {
        // Extent report logic
    }
}
```

If you need Extent report logic in multiple step definition classes, consider creating another class and use [context injection](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Context-Injection.html) to get the object:

```
public class ExtentReportUtils
{
    // common Extent Report logic and methods here
}

[Binding]
public class SpecflowHooks
{
    IObjectContainer container;

    public SpecflowHooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [Before]
    public void Before()
    {
        var utils = new ExtentReportUtils();

        container.RegisterInstanceAs(utils);
    }
}
```

And to use it in a step definition (or even the `ExtentReports` class above):

```
[Binding]
public class YourSteps
{
    ExtentReportUtils extentUtils;

    public YourSteps(ExtentReportUtils extentUtils)
    {
        this.extentUtils = extentUtils;
    }

    [Given(@"...")]
    public void GivenX()
    {
        extentUtils.Foo(...);
    }
}
```